# Invalid Column Name Projectgroup_NAM

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My query in SQL Sever:

```
INSERT INTO BIT_Dashboard.dse.L_Projectgroup (Projectgrouptype_CD) VALUES
(
CASE Projectgroup_NAM

    WHEN ( 
         'BLA'
        | 'BI Projekt'
        | 'PDP'
        | 'VBM'
        ) THEN ('PRO')
END
)
```

I am getting the following error: 
"Invalid column name 'Projectgroup_NAM'."

he thing is (maybe I forgot to emphasise that) is that I already have some rows in the table and I would like to update the Projectgrouptype_CD in the certain row with the query. What am I doing wrong?

Wha is my query not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change it to `select statement`:

```
INSERT INTO BIT_Dashboard.dse.L_Projectgroup (Projectgrouptype_CD)
select
   CASE 
      WHEN Projectgroup_NAM in('BLA','BI Projekt','PDP','VBM') 
        THEN ('PRO')
   END
from BIT_Dashboard.dse.L_Projectgroup
```

I'm not sure table `BIT_Dashboard.dse.L_Projectgroup` is correct, but It's an example.

Update syntax:

```
update BIT_Dashboard.dse.L_Projectgroup
  set Projectgrouptype_CD = 'PRO'
WHERE Projectgroup_NAM in('BLA','BI Projekt','PDP','VBM')
```

If you need more `case`

```
update BIT_Dashboard.dse.L_Projectgroup
      set Projectgrouptype_CD = 
        case 
          WHEN Projectgroup_NAM in('BLA','BI Projekt','PDP','VBM') then 'PRO'
          WHEN Projectgroup_NAM in('BIT') then 'BIT'
        END
```

Comment: from where the value of Projectgroup_NAM should come here?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near 'T'.

Comment: Query is functioning, but it is adding new lines - The thing is (maybe I forgot to emphasise that) is that I already have some rows in the table and I would like to update the Projectgrouptype_CD in the certain row with the query. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Parado,thanks, this looks great. What when I have more case statements? Like: WHEN Projectgroup_NAM IN (
   'BIT'
  ) THEN ('BIT')

Comment: can that be placed in the same query?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

here Projectgroup_NAM column should be from a table.Here I guess you are inserting values from another table1

```
INSERT INTO BIT_Dashboard.dse.L_Projectgroup (Projectgrouptype_CD) 
select CASE when Projectgroup_NAM in('BLA'
        ,'BI Projekt'
        , 'PDP'
        , 'VBM'
        ) THEN 'PRO'
END

from table1
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo Sample data**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7e1df/8)